# does facebook sdk still need manual initialization on android?

Tags: android, facebook, initialization, deprecated

Although `FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize` is deprecated.We still have one(!) user for which app crashes with the following stacktrace:

> Fatal Exception: com.facebook.FacebookSdkNotInitializedException
>   The SDK has not been initialized, make sure to call FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize() first.
>   com.facebook.internal.Validate.sdkInitialized
>   com.facebook.internal.Validate.sdkInitialized (Validate.java:144)
>   com.facebook.login.LoginManager. (LoginManager.java:80)
>   com.facebook.login.LoginManager.getInstance (LoginManager.java:93)
>   ...

SDK version is `com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:5.5.1`

Do I still need to init it manualy?